# What is the different between normal Android virtual machine and Google API virtual machine in Dalvik

Tags: android, google-api, virtual-machine, dalvik, signed

Well, I do not know what is the different between the two virtual machine above. I just know that after I add the signed APIkey to the project, I can not run it with Android virtual machine. In this situation, I have to test it using Google API virtual machine. Could anybody explain it to me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two virtual machines is that the "normal" or "vanilla" version does not include the google services libraries, so it will not work with applications which require those libraries. Similarly, devices from manufactures which do not purchase those libraries or provide replacements will also not work for apps requiring those libraries.

Comment: Do you mean some library like google maps, google voice, etc?

Comment: Google maps is the primary example. There are others, which I do not know off the top of my head. When you want to use a library like google maps, you have to add a line to your manifest like `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`. This library `com.google.android.maps` is available in the Google version of the sdk but not the normal version.